# How to distinguish between JSON null value and default java null in java pojo

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, camel-cxf

I am understanding below JSON

> {    "id": "1",    "value": "some value"   }

> {    "id": "2",    "value": null   }

> {    "id": "3"   }

To hold the above JSON data I have java class :

```
    class myClass
    {
       private String id;
       private String value;
       public String getId() {
        return id;
       }
       public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
       }
       public String getValue() {
        return value;
       }
       public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
      }
}
```

In above example : id 2 and id 3 both have value as NULL

In java it is very difficult to identify the distinguish between passed null value in JSON and other field which are not passed hence java pojo has its default value as NULL.

For me value of id 2 & id 3 should not be same.

Is it possible to distinguish between provided JSON NULL & and default NULL in java?

Comment: You need to specify which json library you're using to unmarshall the json. It's likely not possible after unmarshalling. The question is: why do you want this? If you really need this, it's most likely a better idea to change your approach.

Comment: You could deserialize it to `Map` to be sure.

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish between those situations? Personally, I usually configure my JSON serialization to just not write null values. Null is null. It should not matter whether that is 'default' or explicit set to null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better not to distinguish `null` and *missing* values at all for the very reason you have to ask this question: This distinction is not easy and may not be possible with all JSON libraries, especially when automatically converting to POJO.

It depends on the JSON library if it works, but you can try to add an additional flag to your POJOs, that is set when the setter is called. For example like this:

```
class MyClass {

    private String value;
    private boolean isSetValue;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        isSetValue = true;
    }

    public boolean getIsSetValue() {
        return isSetValue;
    }
}
```

If you plan to serialize this POJO, you need to exclude `getIsSetValue` from serialization and you likely need to modify the JSON serializer to use `getIsSetValue` to decide whether to write a `null` value or no value at all.

Comment: By adding @JsonIgnore on isSetValue i am able to ignore serialization/de-serialization.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible solution I can imagine: Track calls to the setter and ensure that the jSON library you use sets explicit null values.

Would give the following results:

- id 1: setter called with "some value"
- id 2: setter called with null
- id 3: setter **NOT** called

Alternative after Torbens comment:
If the library doesn't use getters/setters, you might be able to use a special value for "unset" and mask that in the getter to return null instead.

Comment: Doesn't work if the JSON library sets the field directly using reflection (like some of them do).

Comment: @Torben you're right of course. Perhaps there are config options to make them use getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
Sting s =  jsonObject.optString("value");
```

for this 
 {    "id": "2",    "value": null   }
it will return null as JAVA Sting

```
jsonObject.optString("value"); // s="null"
```

and for this
 {    "id": "3"   }
it will return null value

```
jsonObject.optString("value"); // s==null
```